# R - ifelse condition query

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a test vector to which I choose weights for each, before calculating the weighted average.

I have a vector x= `x` which is: `0.97109891 1.02659028 0.05549137`

In my function, I perform this, which assigns weights to a new vector:

```
       newVec <- ifelse( x < 1, 1, 
        ifelse( ((1 <= x) && (x < 2)), 0.5, 0 ) )
```

The newVec returns as: `1 0 1`...

Which means the second condition is coming out as `False` and returning `0` when it should be `True` and returning `1`. (new vector should be: `1, 0.5, 1` seems `1 <= 1.0265902`)

I've tested it outside the program and the the result comes back as true... So unless I'm overseeing something I can't work out why it doesn't work in the function...

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ifelse is vectorized. it makes no sense to use it with &&. you should get a warning ix lengt of x is greater than 1 and only the first elem of x is used. & as opposed to && is vectorized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` only checks the first value of the vector.  Use `&` to check element wise.

Comment: Oops. Silly mistake. Problem solved. Thanks for posting.